# Set the field values to the values from the selected record in tree Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

In my application, the two components Ext.tree.Panel and Ext.form.Panel
When I click on the tree entry I need to set the field values ​​to the values ​​from the selected record.

When I click on the entry, the event handler function in the controller is triggered:

```
...
showDataFields: function(view, record, item, index, event) {
    //got a form with fields
    var panel = view.up('mainpanel');
    var formfield = panel.down('mainform');
    //got the selected entry in the tree
    sel = view.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
    console.log(sel)
    //How to assign values from selected record to form fields?
}
...
```

How can i do this?
Example in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nle)

The `showDataFields` method in the controller file on line 37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`loadRecord`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-loadRecord), which will map your record data to your form by `name` property. First retrieve form and then set your record to it:

```
showDataFields: function(view, record, item, index, event) {

    ...

    var form = panel.down('storagepaneltype');
    form.loadRecord(record);
}
```

Also, you need to change "name" property from `name` to `text` to make form match record property. In `Fiddle.view.StoragePanel`:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'text',             //<-- here
    fieldLabel: 'Наименование',
    itemId: 'name_field',
    value: '',
    //bind: '{person.name}'
}
```

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nlf)

Comment: Thank you.Why do you refer to 'panel.down ('storagepaneltype')' and not to lower components, for example to 'panel.down ('mainform')'. Or is there no difference?

Comment: There is no difference